# How can I display image tags in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I would like to display docker container tags in Kubernetes. Currently I deploy my services with helm. My images look like this:

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-service
        image: my-service:latest
```

The image my-service.latest has tags like git commit hash and branch name. In helm I do not know about the image tags, so it is not possible to set the tags over helm with "--set".

What is the way in Kubernetes to read the image tags?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to get what tags are currently running, this is what I've used the past:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}" | tr -s ' ' '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

> In helm I do not know about the image tags, so it is not possible to set the tags over helm with "--set".

Yes you can update image tag using helm. I have used it with jenkins before.

```
helm upgrade  demo ./demo/ -f app/demo.yaml --set image.repository=3xxxxx55.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/demo,image.tag=$BUILD_NUMBER --install --namespace demo --wait --timeout 600 --kube-context demo.k8s.net
```

Also you can use [kubectl to update image tags](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is necessary to deploy a helm release without building your images. I solved my problem as followed:

Add additional tags after cloud build like git branch, commit hash and build time.
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/container/images/add-tag

In the last step of my deployment pipeline I patch the labels of my deployments with

```
kubectl patch deployment
```

command. That works for me quite well.