# Helm chart value based on namespace annotation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

In a helm chart is it possible to set a value at deployment time that is based on an annotation from the namespace it is being deployed to?

Comment: Could you please elaborate how it would look? Not sure if you would like to use [--set](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/) - `--set: Specify overrides on the command line.` or using `helm syntax` specify this in `values.yaml`.

Comment: Sorry, not using set, it is in the chart itself so one value in a statefulset, that when deployed in different clusters will have the value of the namespace annotation based on that cluster

Answer (score 2):

Current versions of Helm 3 have a [`lookup` template function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function) that can retrieve object data from the cluster.  You could use this in this context as something like:

```
{{- $ns := lookup "v1" "Namespace" "" .Release.Namespace }}
{{- $istio := index $ns.metadata.annotations "istio-injection" }}
{{- if eq $istio "enabled" }}
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
...
{{ end }}
```

The documentation has the important caveat that `lookup` doesn't work in `helm template` or `helm install --dry-run` since these modes don't contact the cluster at all; `lookup` will return `nil`.

Also note that this will only take effect when you re-run a `helm` command.  A custom Kubernetes operator might be a little more effort to build, but it will get re-triggered whenever an object you're watching changes, which will behave a little more consistently with other Kubernetes objects.  (That is to say, you could write an operator to automatically create or delete or modify resources whenever the annotation value changes.)

Comment: (This uses the [Go `text/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) `index` function.  Helm and the Sprig extension library include a map-specific `get` function, but `index $map "key"` works as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set different values based on `namespace` and `kube-context` as well. Check this out for reference -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63982817/6673707